# Why must I use a computed property, instead of a stored property, to access convertPoint()

Tags: swift

I'm learning Swift Language by following Stanford University Course.
In lecture five, there is a demo to draw a smile face.

There is a declaration of faceCenter, the code showed as below.

```
var faceCenter: CGPoint {
    return convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
}
```

But my question is why can I use simply equal like below?

```
var faceCenter: CGPoint = convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
```

When I did it, the system gives this error, "Extra argument "fromView" in call".

Can anyone tell me the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because `self` is not initialised yet. Every value has to be assigned before `self` becomes available.

It actually tries to use self three times :

```
var faceCenter: CGPoint = self.convertPoint(self.center, fromView: self.superview)
```

Unfortunately the compiler is not really helpful with this error.

---

You can always make it an optional or give it a default value. Then give it the correct value in the init method.

It is possible to create a `stored property` while also accessing `self`, without assigning the value in the init method. This involves the method in `faceCenterBeta`. It is declared with `lazy` to assign a value to it when it is first read, not when the object is initialised. It also uses a `closure` instead of a `getter` to get the value.

```
class Test : UIView {

    var faceCenter : CGPoint = CGPointZero // give a default value, give correct value in the init method

    var faceCenterAlpha: CGPoint { // getter
        print("getter")
        return convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
    }

    lazy var faceCenterBeta: CGPoint = { [unowned self] in // closure
        print("closure")
        return self.convertPoint(self.center, fromView: self.superview)
        }()

    func faceCenterDelta() -> CGPoint { // good ol' function
        print("function")
        return convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        faceCenter = convertPoint(center, fromView: superview)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

let test = Test()

// executed every time, just like a function
test.faceCenterAlpha
test.faceCenterAlpha
test.faceCenterAlpha

// only executed once
test.faceCenterBeta
test.faceCenterBeta
test.faceCenterBeta
```